# [hiredis]Multiple hincrbys only return one result(REDIS_REPLY_INTEGER)

Tags: c++, redis, hiredis

When using hiredis, use redisAppendCommand to put multiple hincrby commands, the reply->type result of redisGetReply is REDIS_REPLY_INTEGER, and only one of the results is returned.
But when I use hmget, the result of reply->type is REDIS_REPLY_ARRAY.

Comment: *use redisAppendCommand to put multiple hincrby commands*: do you mean call `redisAppendCommand` multiple times to send multiple hincrby commands?

Comment: @for_stack yes, that is what i mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you call `redisAppendCommand` multiple times, you should call `redisGetReply` the same number of times to get all replies. For each reply, it's of type `REDIS_REPLY_INTEGER`. Because the reply type of `hincrby` is integer type, or array type.

The reply type of `hmget` is array reply, and that's why you get `REDIS_REPLY_ARRAY`.

Since you tag the question with `c++`, you can try [redis-plus-plus](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-plus-plus/), which is a user-friendly C++ client for Redis and you don't need to parse the reply manually:

```
auto r = sw::redis::Redis("tcp://127.0.0.1:6379");
for (auto idx = 0; idx < 5; ++idx) {
    r.hincrby("key", "field", 1);
}
std::vector<std::string> fields = {"f1", "f2"};
std::vector<std::optinal<std::string>> vals;
r.hmget("key", fields.begin(), fields.end(), std::back_inserter(vals));
```

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of redis-plus-plus.*

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for answering my question.
And the official reply from HIREDIS is here.
https://github.com/redis/hiredis/issues/1143

```
This is correct given the specifications of both commands.

The hmget command returns an array reply, while hincrby returns an. integer.

Here is a small example that appends several HINCRBY commands and then prints each of the replies.
```

Comment: this should be a comment in for_stack's answer, not an answer itself.